# reformat entry-title with two different styles

Tags: title

I would like to apply two different styles for entry-title

meaning i.e. "my services: this big"

"my services:" should appear with default font size
"This Big" should appear with bigger font size
detection char for bigger font would be ":"
so if there is a ":" in title, everything afterwards should be xy bigger

I tried for hours already in functions.php, I am to stupid
thanks for help

Comment: I found this in my content-page.php, will try to edit:

<?php if ( the_title( '', '', false ) && siteorigin_page_setting( 'page_title' ) ) : ?>
     <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 0):

ok found out - added this to my content-page.php
maybe not nice, but works for now...

```
    <?php $pieces = explode(':', the_title( '', '', false ), 2 ); if (2 == count($pieces)) : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><span><span style="font-size: 24px;"><?php print $pieces[0]; ?>: </span><span><?php print $pieces[1]; ?></span></span></h1>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```